# How do I fix this Mysql1 query connection error message?

Tags: flutter, mysql-connector

I am using mysql1 with my flutter frontend, and connecting it to a mysql database on localhost.

However, it has all come crashing and burning. This is the error message when I try to establish a connection and run a query:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 7
#0      _ByteDataView.getUint16 (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:5148:7)
#1      Buffer.readUint16 (package:mysql1/src/buffer.dart:240:24)
#2      new PrepareOkPacket (package:mysql1/src/prepared_statements/prepare_ok_packet.dart:20:30)
#3      Handler.checkResponse (package:mysql1/src/handlers/handler.dart:68:24)
#4      PrepareHandler.processResponse (package:mysql1/src/prepared_statements/prepare_handler.dart:45:18)
#5      ReqRespConnection._handleData (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:355:32)
#6      ReqRespConnection._handleHeader (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:324:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ReqRespConnection._readPacket (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:309:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

It would be great if someone knows how to fix this. Or I can just use another flutter mysql package...

I have tried to research this error as it is not a quick fix. But I have been told that I need to inspect the package's source code and I do not have the expertise neither time to do this